# Enter key not triggering submit button

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, enter

My page has two forms. One is a normal login form, the other is for creating account and appears in a modal box. I used Javascript (below) to have the enter key submit the "create account" form, and it works great. for some reason, however, the exact same code used in the exact same manner won't work for the login form. Can anyone explain this to me?

I used this script:

```
<script>function checkSubmit(e)
{
   if(e && e.keyCode == 13)
   {
      document.forms[0].submit();
   }
}
</script>
```

and I implemented it in a link like this:

```
<a href="editprofile.php" onclick="document.createfrm.submit()"  onKeyPress="return checkSubmit(event)" id="submitcreate">
```

when I enter the "onKeyPress" stuff in a similar link for the login form, it doesn't work. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Use a real submit button and the form will submit when enter is pressed, no javascript required.

Comment: `onKeyPress` on an anchor link? That assumes that the browser supports keyboard focus on an `<a>`, and that the focus remains on it until enter is pressed. How is it focused in the first place if clicking also triggers a submit?

Comment: @steele what browser are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<a href="javascript:document.createfrm.submit()" id="submitcreate">
```